# Camel: How to join back to a single path after multicast?

Tags: java, apache-camel

This seems like an incredibly simple problem but I've tried everything I can think of. Basically I have a timer route that sends its message to a bunch of different beans. Those beans set a property on the exchange (I've also tried a header on the message) and I want the exchange output from all of those beans to be directed to a filter (which checks for the property or header) and then optionally another endpoint. Something like this:

```
                       ---> Bean A ---
                      /               \
timer --> multicast ------> Bean B ------> end --> filter --> endpoint
                      \               /
                       ---> Bean C ---
```

Currently the route looks like this, and it works for multicasting to the beans:

```
from("timer://my-timer?fixedRate=true&period=20000&delay=0")
  .multicast()
    .to("bean:beanA", "bean:beanB", "bean:beanC");
```

Here are the some of the solutions I've tried:

**Solution 1**

```
from("timer://my-timer?fixedRate=true&period=20000&delay=0")
  .multicast()
    .to("bean:beanA", "bean:beanB", "bean:beanC")
  .filter(new myPredicate())
    .to("myOptionalEndpoint");
```

This puts the filter in parallel with the beans instead of after them.

**Solution 2**

```
from("timer://my-timer?fixedRate=true&period=20000&delay=0")
  .multicast()
    .to("bean:beanA", "bean:beanB", "bean:beanC")
  .end()
  .filter(new myPredicate())
    .to("myOptionalEndpoint");
```

Does the beans in parallel and then does the filter. However, the properties/headers are not set. It seems like the exchange is fresh off the timer and is not the one that went through the beans...

**Edit:** I tried setting the body and in fact the message that arrives at the filter has no body. I can't imagine `Camel` would somehow shuck the payload of the message so I have to assume that this exchange is a new one from the timer, not one that went through the beans. However, it happens *after* the beans are done.

**Solution 3**

```
from("timer://my-timer?fixedRate=true&period=20000&delay=0")
  .multicast()
    .beanRef("beanA").to("direct:temp")
    .beanRef("beanB").to("direct:temp")
    .beanRef("beanC").to("direct:temp")
  .end()

from("direct:temp")
  .filter(new myPredicate())
    .to("myOptionalEndpoint");
```

Messages reach the filter as expected but the properties/headers that I set are gone so no messages pass the filter.

**Edit:** The body is gone here too so clearly I am not getting the same exchange that is coming from the beans...

To clarify, I am looking for a solution where the a single exchange from the timer is multicasted to each bean (so now we have 3 exchanges) and each of these 3 is then sent to the filter.

Can anybody help me figure out how to build this route?

Comment: Use aggregation strategy to merge the mutlicasts together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, inspired by Kalman's:

```
from("timer://my-timer?fixedRate=true&period=20000&delay=0")
  .multicast()
    .to("direct:a", "direct:b", "direct:c")
  .end()

from("direct:a").beanRef("beanA").to("direct:temp")
from("direct:b").beanRef("beanB").to("direct:temp")
from("direct:c").beanRef("beanC").to("direct:temp")

from("direct:temp")
  .filter(new myPredicate())
    .to("myOptionalEndpoint");
```

This was a more complicated solution that I was expecting. There must be a more elegant way to achieve this but the above solution works. Obviously use different names than a, b, c and temp though...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an aggregation strategy in order to aggregate all the results into one.

Below is a great example from http://javarticles.com/2015/05/apache-camel-multicast-examples.html (See the `Multicast with a Custom Aggregation Strategy` section)

```
public class CamelMulticastAggregationExample {
  public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JndiContext jndiContext = new JndiContext();
    jndiContext.bind("myBean", new MyBean());
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(jndiContext);
    try {
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                .multicast()
                .aggregationStrategy(new JoinReplyAggregationStrategy())
                .to("direct:a", "direct:b", "direct:c")
                .end()
                .to("stream:out");

                from("direct:a")
                .to("bean:myBean?method=addFirst");

                from("direct:b")
                .to("bean:myBean?method=addSecond");

                from("direct:c")
                .to("bean:myBean?method=addThird");
            }
        });
        ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        camelContext.start();
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "Multicast");
    } finally {
        camelContext.stop();
    }
  }
```

}

where `JoinReplyAggregationStrategy` class looks as follows

```
public class JoinReplyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

  public Exchange aggregate(Exchange exchange1, Exchange exchange2) {
    if (exchange1 == null) {
        return exchange2;
    } else {
        String body1 = exchange1.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String body2 = exchange2.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String merged = (body1 == null) ? body2 : body1 + "," + body2;
        exchange1.getIn().setBody(merged);
        return exchange1;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** In your case, your aggregation strategy might be to gather all of your exchanges together as follows:

```
public class ListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
            Message newIn = newExchange.getIn();
            Object newBody = newIn.getBody();
            List list = null;
            if (oldExchange == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList();
                    list.add(newBody);
                    newIn.setBody(list);
                    return newExchange;
            } else {
                    Message in = oldExchange.getIn();
                    list = in.getBody(List.class);
                    list.add(newBody);
                    return oldExchange;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using that `AggregationStrategy` will join the 3 exchanges in the 3 beans into a single exchange that will go through the filter. I want to keep the 3 different exchanges and have each one go through the filter separately. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: I reread your question and updated my answer. See if my update addresses your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, no AggregationStrategy will work as I need to preserve the headers/properties per message. Your answer did inspire a solution though so thank you.

Comment: Also I would say in general for this type of problem an AggregationStrategy would be the solution. This route is a little unique in that the message is not actually important at the beginning - it's just a ping from a timer to activate the route at a certain interval. So after the multicast you could consider each exchange to be distinct. I could equally have just made separate routes (but in reality there are many more than 3 beans so that would have been impractical)

Answer (score 1):

Use scatter gather EIP instead of multicast !